# Disable function when other function is running

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I have two event listeners and they are both fired on pageload depending on a video state. But if both are fired, I want the first one to stop running. How is that possible?

```js
obj.addEventListener('suspend', () => {
  // when only this is fired -> run this code
  
  // my code
});

obj.addEventListener('play', () => {
  // when this is fired too -> run this code and deactivate the first code
  
  // my code
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a global variable and check if it is true , not to fire the  first function.
But there may be some runtime problems , if between running the first event , second event called , first event will not freeze and continues to run.

```
let shouldRun = true;
obj.addEventListener('suspend', () => {
  // when only this is fired -> run this code

if(!shouldRun){
  return;
}
// my code
});

obj.addEventListener('play', () => {
  // when this is fired too -> run this code and deactivate the first code
  shouldRun = false;
  // my code
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, both functions still run..

Comment: can you please clear when will these events call? both on a same time or first `play` calls and then `suspend` or some other orders?

Comment: The suspend event calls first every time, then the play event..

Answer (score 0):

I guess You can try  using obj.removeEventListener('suspend') on the Call of 'play' event.

For more about removeEventListener, you can go through the official link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good solution but I am getting an Error "Not enough arguments". Do you know what I have to add here?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this is to remove the event handler with [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

```
function handleSuspend() {
  // when only this is fired -> run this code
  
  // my code
}

function handlePlay() {
  // when this is fired too -> run this code and deactivate the first code
  obj.removeEventListener('suspend', handleSuspend);
  
  // my code
}

obj.addEventListener('suspend', handleSuspend);
obj.addEventListener('play', handlePlay);
```